# How to get dependencies tree?

Tags: python, django

I have model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=True)
    [...]
```

And I want to get all dependencies tree, for example:

```
user1 -> childs: user2, user3, user4
user2 -> childs: user5, user6
user3 -> childs: user7, user8
etc.
```

In my case I want to get list:

```
[
    (user1, user2),
    (user1, user3),
    (user1, user4),
    (user2, user5),
    (user2, user6),
    (user3, user7),
    (user3, user8),
]
```

How to do it?

Comment: Isn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486520/making-a-tree-structure-in-django-models what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

In pseudocode:

```
for each MyUser element e:
    get the related elements (for e.pk)
    print the result
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835688/how-to-return-multiple-objects-related-with-foreignkey-in-django) may be of some use.